# Change just the year of a date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm trying to change the year of all of the birthdates to **2005** like the **`SEND CARD`** column.

I have three rows:

| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | BIRTHDATE | SEND CARD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sue | Doe | 01-JUL-1980 | July 2005 |
| Bob | Miller | 19-MAR-1979 | March 2005 |
| Monique | Tuttle | 30-MAR-1069 | March 2005 |

I can truncate it to have the **`SEND CARD`** be

```
01-JUL-1980 
01-MAR-1979 
01-MAR-1969
```

Which is what I want, but I need to year to be **2005**. How do I change just the year?

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, birthdate, TRUNC(birthdate, 'Month')
  FROM f_staffs;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to complicate it that much; a simpler option is

```
TO_CHAR (birthdate, 'fmMonth') || ' 2005' AS send_card
```

Sample data:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     f_staffs (first_name, birthdate)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 'Sue', DATE '1980-07-01' FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 'Bob', DATE '1979-03-19' FROM DUAL
  7         UNION ALL
  8         SELECT 'Monique', DATE '1969-03-30' FROM DUAL)
```

Query:

```
  9  SELECT first_name,
 10         birthdate,
 11         TO_CHAR (birthdate, 'fmMonth') || ' 2005' AS send_card
 12    FROM f_staffs;

FIRST_N BIRTHDATE   SEND_CARD
------- ----------- --------------
Sue     01-jul-1980 July 2005
Bob     19-mar-1979 March 2005
Monique 30-mar-1969 March 2005

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer in case anyone asks in the future!

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, To_CHAR(birthdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS "BIRTHDATE", TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(birthdate, ((2005 - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM birthdate)) * 12)), 'Month'), 'Month YYYY') AS "SEND CARD"
FROM f_staffs;
```